# Naming PDF files in FPDF while generating PDF online on my website

Tags: php, filenames, fpdf

I am generating PDFs and emailing it to users , on my website dynamically using FPDF. But the name of the PDFs generated contains slashes and plus signs ( + , / , \ , [ , ] ) etc. due to which the following error occurs :

```
fopen:( Unable to find the file or directory )
```

as soon as I remove the slashes and braces , the PDF is generated successfully and emailed too.

Need a solution to deal with the file-names?
The filenames are created dynamically , so it is not in my hand to change them ? So I think I need to first strip off all those special characters from the PDF file name and then send it to FPDF output. But how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `urlencode`:

```
 file_put_contents(urlencode('asd#$%21234 /&11 /!@##$$%&&*()_'), 'test');
```

But then you get strange chars.

Or you just can strip and leave allowed chars

```
 file_put_contents(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_\-]/', '','asd#$%21234 /&11 /!@##$$%&&*()_'), 'test');
```

Comment: Actually, you can't `base64_encode` since `/` is one of the characters in base 64.

Comment: It just came to me, you can't use `[raw]urlencode` either. The reason is the percent-encoding (all the major OSes don't accept percent signs `%` in their filenames). Sorry for being a PITA...

Comment: @Alix Axel No worries, i understand. I just quick tested on my Linux machine and it was working fine. By wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_name, the only operating system what uses % as special char is RT-11

Comment: You're totally right, my bad. I read the description for `*` instead. =)

Answer (score 1):

I think that slashes cannot be used in file name because it is also used to determine file path. For instance a file nammed foo/bar.php is actually a file named bar.php but in foo folder.

A workaround may be to first create foo directory. Then when you ask for "foo/bar.php" file, you'll get bar.php file from foo directory (not tested).

Or you can remove all unwanted characters. For my projects I use this to "normalize" text:

$string = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]+#', '-', $string);

Comment: So , I need to first strip off all those special characters from the PDF file name . But how to do this ?

Comment: So, `WWII.pdf` would become `-----pdf`?

Comment: You can adapt the mask to your specific purpose. For this question a-zA-Z0-9 may be better :-)

Comment: include the . in the regular expression or apply the normalization first then add .pdf

Answer (score 1):

[OWASP ESAPI4PHP](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/source/browse/#svn/trunk) library has some very decent sanitizers for file names and other types data.

See also **[comparison of filename limitations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations)**.